# What readers are available at the 1,000 word level?

Tags: resources, reading

I want to improve my reading and grammar skills by finding interesting things to read. What graded readers, basic textbooks, magazines, and other reading materials are available for adult students who can recognize the first 1,000 words from the HSK? I would prefer material which includes a CD or MP3 files, but without is okay too.

Comment: @Alenanno - This is very close to being a dup. but that question is for 2k - 3k. I think 1k words is a good distinction for someone who has gone past the beginner level.

Comment: @Village, 
This doesn't feel like the right place to talk about this, but I'm working on a website that might be just what you're looking for. It's going into private beta this weekend, and I'll need learners like you to test it out, so if you're interested, please [sign up to be a beta tester](http://3000hanzi.com/).

Comment: @stevendaniels - that looks interesting - I've added my name to the list as well, so feel free to sign me up when it comes out :-)

Comment: My teacher at Copenhagen University told me that at the level of 2000 characters you can read a Chinese newspaper. So guess you can read half a newspaper!

Comment: Can you read an English newspaper with a vocab of 2000 English words? I'll say yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [读者](http://www.duzhe.com/) which is like Reader's Digest. I don't know if one with 1000 words can understand every article in it, but I think you can find some interesting essays.

Answer (score 1):

Anna mei Banfa! (an early level 2 reader) may be excruciatingly repetitious, but it's a good way to pound those most frequent characters into your head. It's used in high school classes in the US. Make it a bit more interesting by making up a parallel story in your mind about another girl who's a lot more interesting (using the same vocab, or looking up just a few more "colorful" expressions!)